# How do I cater for overflow inside the the flexibleSpace of a SliverAppBar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have SliverAppBar that scrolls inside CustomScroll view, I realized once I added in text and begin to scroll the bottom of the SliverAppBar begins to overflow.

The behavior that I want is that immediately when I start scrolling the Sliver App Bar must begin to start scrolling too so there's no overflow. (The distance between the app bar and the Tabbar must always be constant)

As you can see in the give, theres overflow once I begin to scroll over the text.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbjJS.jpg) is what I mean.

Build method:

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollViewController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              expandedHeight: 400,
              forceElevated: boxIsScrolled,
              flexibleSpace: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    overflow: Overflow.visible,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        image: NetworkImage(
                            'https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/soccer-field-spotlight-background-stadium_46250-1363.jpg'),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        bottom: -75,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45),
                              child: Text.rich(
                                TextSpan(
                                  children: <TextSpan>[
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: '22K',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    TextSpan(text: '\n'),
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: 'Connections',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                              ),
                            ),
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                              child: Image(
                                width: 130,
                                height: 130,
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://lookyourbestbeyourbest.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/image-3.jpeg',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45),
                              child: Text.rich(
                                TextSpan(
                                  children: <TextSpan>[
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: '12K',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    TextSpan(text: '\n'),
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: 'Connections',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 85,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: 'John Dory',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    text: "Home",
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Example page",
                    icon: Icon(Icons.help),
                  )
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageOne(),
            PageTwo(),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.control_point),
        onPressed: () {
          _tabController.animateTo(1,
              curve: Curves.bounceInOut, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10));

      
          _scrollViewController
              .jumpTo(_scrollViewController.position.maxScrollExtent);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry it so much code.
Thank you

Comment: try removing `pinned: true,` from SliverAppBar

Comment: tried that, same thing. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: can you change `NestedScrollView` to `CustomScrollView`? Slivers are used with CustomScrollView.

Comment: basically you can return slivers as CustomScrollView supports list of slivers. First child can be SliverAppBar followed by SliverList or any other sliver you would want.

Comment: Thanks, I changed  ` NestedScrollView` to ` CustomScrollView` and I got exceptions. Do you possibly have an example?